# Php - How can I display time followed my selected value in same input field

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I display date followed by a string selected from the dropdown list in Php? I have 8 department options for a user to select from. Once a department is selected then the user clicks the button. Depending on what department was selected. Department abbreviation needs to show up in the input field followed by time.when that button is pressed the page should issue an AJAX request with the department chosen to another PHP file on the server to get a PO number, formatted like ${DEPT}${Year}${Month}${Day w/ Leading zero}.

I have got the date down so far. but not sure how to include the selected value and date together to output.

```
`var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

        if(day < 10){
            day = '0' + day
            }

        if (mm < 10){
            month = '0' + month
             }

        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML =("<b>" + day + "/" + 
          month + "/" + year + "</b>");`
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can doit like so

```
<div>
   <input type="text" id="show-input">
   <select id="dept">
       <option value="option1">option1</option>
       <option value="option2">option2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" id="save">
<div>
```

then in you main js file

```
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', () => {
   const dept = document.querySelector("#dept").value;
   const date = new Date().toDateString(); // you can getDay() or getYear()
   document.querySelector('#show-input').value = dept + date
});
```